# how to connect powerpivot to oraclesqldeveloper

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, powerpivot

I am trying to connect the oracle sql developer and import one of the databases into the power pivot.

A.  I am trying to connect to "Oracle Database" option in power pivot and unable to get the server name from the database I want to connect to. How can I retrieve and know what to enter in the import wizard for oracle in power pivot. Is that the right place to connect to in the first place?

B.  The oracle SQL developer information that I have is in the screenshot. Please let me know which of these value can be input in the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHUdc.png) screenshot.

[image: what information from 2 to be entered in 1]

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus might be not appropriate here.

Comment: sorry, what would be the right place then for something like this?

Comment: Probably something like superuser.com or serverfault.com, but there might be even better places.

Comment: Hi Team,Can someone help here. I am unable to get traction on either of those 2 websites.